# Finding multiple exact value

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to query elastic search , query if field is one of a list
how do I do that in elastic 6.0.0? 
for example these are my documents:

```
{"name" : "jim","company": "a"}
{"name" : "jack","company": "a"}
{"name" : "joe","company": "b"}
{"name" : "foo","company": "b"}
{"name" : "bar","company": "c"}
{"name" : "boe","company": "c"}
{"name" : "jee","company": "d"}
```

Id like to return all entries which have company `a` or `b`

i tried this:

```
curl  -u elastic:password -XPOST 'localhost:9243/my-index/_search?size=2000&pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "size": 2000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"term": {"company": ["a","b"]}}

      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

but I get an error `[term] query does not support array of values`

note: I need a solution that would let me use an array, since I need to match ~100 options (100 companies - in the above example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) is what you are looking for.

Replace `term` with `terms`. Term doesn't accept array, whereas terms does.

```
{
  "size": 2000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "company": ["a","b"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```